# Ubuntu server, turn off screen via ssh

Tags: server, ssh, display, screen, monitor

I got a laptop running Ubuntu Server 16.04 **without** a GUI.

Is there a way to turn off the screen via ssh?

I've already tried: (as root and as simple user with sudo)

```
sudo vbetool dpms off  
> no effect
```

and:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
xset -display :0 dpms force off
> xset:  unable to open display ":0"
```

and:

```
xrandr -q
> Can't open display
```